# How to redirect users based on what they type in an input?

Tags: javascript

I have a form like this:

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="url" placeholder="Enter URL Address">
  <input type="submit" value="go!">
</form>
```

And I want users to be redirected to a URL based on what they wrote in the URL input when they click the submit button.
Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask to not get voted down and get nasty comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function() {
    var url = this.url.value;
    if (url) location=url;
    return false;
  }
}
```

using

```
<form id="form1">
  <input type="url" placeholder="Enter URL Address">
  <input type="submit" value="go!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the `window.location` for this specific case. You can throw any string in there and the browser will redirect to that page.

EDIT:
You do not need a whole form for that. The form is used to send data to the server - the thing you want here is client-sided and does not require a form. You can use a simple input field with a simple button that fires a bit of javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes jane it is possible. You can do that by javascript or php.

example on javascript:

```
// Put an id on your form and change the id below accordingly
var idForm = 'form';
var form = $('#' + idForm);
form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var redirectTo = form.find('input').val();
    switch(redirectTo) {
       case "INPUT_VALUE_EXAMPLE":
          window.location = 'YOUR URL HERE';
          break;
       case "google"
          window.location = 'http://www.google.com'
          break;
     }
});
```